# Laravel error when uploading to remote server

Tags: php, laravel, remote-server

I've uploaded my Laravel project to my remote server without SSH Acces, following this tutorial:

http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Briefly, what I've done:

- In my domain directory I've created the '/laravel' directory
- I've put my laravel folders in this directory
- I've put the content of the public folder in 'public_html'
- I've edited the links of 'bootstrap/paths.php'
- I've edited the links of 'public_html/index.php'

Everything should work fine now, however when visiting the site I get this strange error from the laravel debugging :

*syntax error, unexpected '['*

which is alledged to be located in

*/home/jamesmr117/domains/jamesmr117.117.axc.nl/laravel/vendor/way/generators/src/Way/Generators/GeneratorsServiceProvider.php*

However, when accessing the very same project locally, there is not a single error showing up.
Would anyone know what could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess your shared hosting is PHP 5.3 or lower once your local server running PHP 5.4 or higher.

Comment: you've probably got something like `somefunc()[0]`, trying to dereference an array return directly.

Comment: @barell Indeed, I've looked it up and my PHP version is 5.3.28 . However the turial didn't mention this as a problem. 
I've changed the extension of the file to .php54, which would, according to my ISP , run the file in PHP 5.4, but the error remains

Comment: Probably it is. You can show the line where the error occurs so we will know it for sure.

Comment: here it is ` public function register()
 {
        foreach([`

Comment: @MarcB It turns out to be in a foreach loop

Comment: So you've got `foreach([...]`, and this is a short syntax which was introduced in PHP 5.4. You can change it to `foreach(array(...)` but I'm afraid there may be more errors like this, because this code looks to be not compatible with PHP 5.3 at all.